# FARM Stack - SameSite="none"; Secure can't be set on logout API call

Tags: mongodb, cookies, jwt, web-farm-framework

I have a backend based on the FARM stack by MongoDB (https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/FARM-Stack-FastAPI-React-MongoDB/), with authentication (https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/FARM-Stack-Authentication/).

[image: FAST API Doc]
Authentication works as it should on Fast API docs and Postman. When executing a successful user log in, it automatically sets the JWT HttpOnly cookie on the browser. When logged in, it removes the cookie again on logout.

When calling /login on front-end, it said following error in the Network tab: [image: Error]

As the error states, I managed to fix this by setting the cookie options on the backend as following, and I could afterwards successfully login from a react front-end: [image: FARM STACK BACKEND]

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for the /logout call. This error occurs again, as the SET-COOKIE header tries to set an empty cookie, yet it can't due to the cookie having a SAMESITE="lax" as default, but I don't see a way to find out how to configure it for the /logout call in the backend.[image: LOGOUT Network]

My front-end /logout call looks like this, the same as /login:

[image: FRONTEND CALL]

How do I configure my front-end/back-end, so my front-end can successfully delete my cookie and successfully log out?

Answer (score 0):

If you see `SameSite='Lax'` as a warning in Chrome that means you don't send the header correctly.

The main issue is about sending a header called `SameSite`, Chrome is a little bit restricted when you have an invalid value the **chrome browser** defaults the **value to `'Lax'`**, I had the same issue with FastAPI a couple of days ago and my issue is sending `None` without string `'None'` like this:

```
# The Correct way
response.set_cookie(key="access_token", value=access_token, samesite='None')

# Incorrect usage
response.set_cookie(key="access_token", value=access_token, samesite=None)
```

When I made this mistake chrome defaults SameSite to STRING `'Lax'`,
This is the issue in general, you need to use `set_cookie` and figure out what you're sending from the backend, and I recommend enabling that only in the development environment.